# How to get notes from Evernote API that have images?

Tags: java, evernote

I currently get notes from Evernote WebClipper API (Java) using the following code. This gets me the notes that have text in them. However, some notes might have images contained in them. I would like to get access to these images (resources). How would I do this?

```
NotesMetadataList nl = evernoteAccount.getRequestedNotes(words);
for (NoteMetadata note : nl.getNotes()) {
  logger.debug("GUID: " + note.getGuid());
  logger.debug("Title: " + note.getTitle());
  logger.debug("Content: " + note.getContent());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Evernote notes can have attachments called resources which includes images.  To download the resources you have 2 options:

1. parse the content of the note for the images for the "en-media" tag.  The tag will have the attributes "type" and "hash". Type will contain the [MIME type of the file](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/resources.php) that is attached to the note as a resource and the "hash" is the MD5 hash of the file.  If the type of the file is one you would like to retrieve call [getResourceByHash](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getResourceByHash) on the note store where the note resides passing the GUID of the note, hash of the file, and true/false to include not include the data, recognition, and alternative data respectively.
2. download the resource associated with the note via the metadata in the note. Each note has a "resources" attribute which is a list of all the resources attached to the note.  Each item in the list represents a resource and will have a "mime" and "guid" attribute.  You can also inspect the attributes.fileName attribute for the file name of the resource.  If the "mime", filename or other attribute of the resource matches your criteria for downloading you can use the [getResourceData](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getResourceData) method on the note store on which the note is contained to download the file by passing the GUID of the *resource* (not the GUID of the note).

Sources:
Evernote API Reference: https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/
Evernote Resources/Attachments: https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/resources.php
Evernote Markup Language (ENML): https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/enml.php